# Is the performance of electronic devices affected by their age?

Tags: electric-circuits, electronics, electrical-engineering

I always wondered what happens inside an electronic component during its lifetime. I am aware that passive or active electronic devices can have their performance decreased over a long period of activity, due to exposure to excessive hot / cold temperatures, humidity, corrosion, etc, but how can an electronic component "get old" if this has been taken care of and it has been exploited within an optimal environment?

Example: My Android based phone which is about $1.5$ years old, started to experience a bit of lag even if it has been restored to factory settings, having the same initial operating system version and without no other applications installed. It's just clearly slowed down by something and for sure it's not related to some cpu throttling due to battery performance as this is still in good shape. I noticed this behavior on almost all Android devices I've owned so far but never on $iOS$ based devices.

My questions is: how can two electronic devices (Android & $iOS$), same age approximately, both restored to factory settings, behave so different in terms of performance after a few years of exploitation?
As it's clearly not a software related issue and excluding the battery, is the quality of the hardware components really so important when comparing two manufacturers? What exactly can define an "aged" component? Dried out capacitors or faulty resistors / transistors? Would these really be the cause of slowed down Android devices across time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In electronic devices of modern manufacture, the three *hardware* component classes that actually degrade with age are 1) batteries, 2) electrolytic capacitors, and 3) wire-to-board interconnects.

Degraded batteries exhibit progressively less charge capacity and eventually will not take a charge at all, but this would not in and of itself cause the device to "run slow".

When electrolytic capacitors degrade, they slowly stop behaving as charge storage devices and begin acting as resistors instead. This causes gross circuit failures (for example, an electronically-tuned FM receiver that no longer responds to tuning commands) but again, this would not in and of itself cause a device to "run slow" either.

When interconnects degrade, signals that are sent through them are degraded by introduction of noise. This can cause data transfer faults which are remedied by automatically retransmitting the data packet until it happens to be fault-free, which slows down the device- but not in a consistently repeatable way.

The most common reason for a digital device to "run slow" is when its free memory is used up or when you are trying to run a new app on an old, overdue-for-upgrade operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, performance of electronic devices is affected by their age. This issue isn't unique to Android phones. If you're not seeing it in iPhones, it could be because Apple is intentionally slowing them down to mask the issue (see [source](https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-42508300)).

> "Lithium-ion batteries become less capable of supplying peak current demands when in cold conditions, [when they] have a low battery charge or as they age over time, which can result in the device unexpectedly shutting down to protect its electronic components," the company said.